# Connecting android app to backend db using self hosted local parse server

Tags: android, mongodb, parse-platform

I have migrated parse database to mongolabs, and I have set up parse example server and in the android app, I have given the above (in the picture) server configuration.

I tested that the server is connecting properly with the db and the app is also able to contact the server (on / route, I just tried printing something on console, so on initialize, app connects to server on / route), but i am unable to get the app to put things in the db. I was wondering how and where parse makes the rest calls.

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
.applicationId("***************")
.clientKey("********************\n")
.server("http://192.168.0.11:1337/parse")
.build()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Your code seems to be right. What is the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Parse server url (.server) is not right. It should be `https://yourAppName.herokuapp.com/parse`. You should have a config variable key called `SERVER_URL` and the value is the server URL above.

Comment: I'm running the server on my localhost (local Machine) first. I wont be deploying the server to heeorku but instead I will be deploying to a server in my university's lab. Do I need to make any specific changes to the URL?

Comment: @SunilKumar If you are hosting it on an actual server rather than Heroku, the address should be ok, but I can't say for sure. I just made the wrong assumption. What error are you getting?